# Evothings and ddp

Tags: meteor, ddp

We are trying to connect our [evothings](https://evothings.com/) app up to a meteor server.

To do this we are using a lib called [asteroid](https://github.com/mondora/asteroid). However we are unable to connect and run methods. We are absolutly sure this is not a server issue since we have some separate client code for testing that works flawlessly with it.

Evothings says it should work with websockets, and we aren't getting any error output, but all our method calls are returning nothing.

Here is the code:

```
var _asteroid = require('asteroid');

var Asteroid = (0, _asteroid.createClass)('password-login');
var asteroid = new Asteroid({ endpoint: 'wss://[url]/websocket' });

var currentLogin = null;

$('#login').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  login($('#login_username').val(), $('#login_password').val());
});
$('#create').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  newUser($('#create_username').val(), $('#create_password').val(), $('#create_id').val());
});
$('#occupy').click(function(event) {
  setStatus(0);
});
$('#vacant').click(function(event) {
  setStatus(1);
});
$('#refreash').click(function() {
  getEmptyRooms();
});

window.newUser = function (username, password, roomId) {
  $('#create_error').text('');
    asteroid.call("accounts.newUser", username, password, roomId).then(function (result) {
        console.log("Success");
        login(username, password);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.error(error);
        $('#create_error').text(error.message);
    });
}

window.login = function (username, password) {
  $('#login_error').text('');
    asteroid.loginWithPassword({ username: username, password: password }).then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        currentLogin = result;
        $('#current').html('Current User: ' + username);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.error(error);
        $('#login_error').text(error.message);
    });;
}

window.getEmptyRooms = function () {
    asteroid.call("rooms.getAvailable").then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('#room_list').empty();
        for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
          $('#room_list').append('<li>' + result[i] + '</li>');
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.error(error);
    });
}

window.setStatus = function (status) {
    $('#status_error').text('');
    if (currentLogin != null) {
        asteroid.call("rooms.setStatus", status).then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.error(error);
            $('#status_error').text(error.message);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('please login first');
        $('#status_error').text('please login first');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the require() function works only in node.js, not in browser environment such as Evothings Viewer or Cordova, so you'll need some alternative means of loading the "asteroid" lib. Browserify?

How did you look for error output? The Evothings Tools window? If so, did you add this snippet to your index.html file?

```
<script>
    // Redirect console.log to Evothings Workbench.
    if (window.hyper && window.hyper.log) { console.log = hyper.log }
</script>
```

Perhaps this error isn't exclusive to the Evothings environment. Have you tested the app in a regular web browser?

Comment: Yeah I actually used browserify and used the output for the evothings app. We know it is trying the calls since each one outputs a disconnect event, it just never connects.

Yeah we have the log output in the Tools window with the whole log thing.

Comment: We also do have a working client in a web browser using the same code and the browserify output.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using proper certs?

Self signed will not work. The Evothings app is served via wss and since it runs "headless" so to speak (not a normal browser) it can't ask the user about allowing a self signed cert, so it will fail. Note that AFAIK *ANY* issue with the cert will make it fail.

Comment: I am using let's encrypt for my certs on the meteor server.

Comment: I wrote an article earlier where I used letsencrypt with VerneMQ (https://evothings.com/evothings-does-mqtt-with-vernemq-or-emqtt/) and one important thing is that you need the FULL chain since the Evothings app doesn't have any intermediate certs bundled with it - as a normal web browser does. But I got it working, so check that article.